# How to convert svg path to list of points in flutter

Tags: flutter, svg

I wrote code to find in SVG string specific path with proper id.

How can I transform the SVG path into a list of points?

Or [svg_path_parser's](https://pub.dev/packages/svg_path_parser) Path can be magically decrypted into list of Offsets? Because Path.contains(offset) method refers to native implementation.

Comment: what points? the package you mention lets you parse your `String` into `Path` object so you can call `contains` method on it

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/path_drawing is this what you are looking for?

Comment: nope, I need exactly points with x and y fields to compare it with my list of points, but flutter Path object does not provide any methods or fields to do that

Comment: check `PathMetric` then